# Xcode and C++ Headers

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a question about using C++ header files in Objective-C++ modules in Xcode. Specifically, why can I #include them in source files but not header files?

Here is a specific example.

I'm using Xcode 7.2.1 and have two projects. The first is a C++ framework I package into "myFramework.framework". It exposes "myFramework.h", which in turn pulls in "myLib.h".  At the top of "myLib.h" is an "#include <string>".

The second project is an Objective-C iOS app which consumes the above framework. In this project, "myViewController.mm" (Objective-C++ source) has "#import "myFramework/myFramework.h" at the top and makes reference to things defined in that header file.

At this point all is well and good.  It builds and runs with no issues.

When I move the "#import myFramework/myFramework.h" line to "myViewController.h", the compile fails because it cannot locate the "" header dependency.

It doesn't matter if I change the file type for "myViewController.h" to Objective-C++ header from plain old "C Header".  Either way, Xcode's header search paths don't look for standard C++ headers.

So my main question is why does it behave this way? Why is a #include/#import treated differently just because it's in a header file?

My second question is if there's some way to make Xcode treat the #include/#import the same when it's in the header file instead of the source file?

Thanks much!

Comment: are you sure that you get the error while compiling the `.mm` file? Isn't perhaps `myViewController.h` imported into some other file (and then that file fails to compile)? BTW, it is not clear if you use `#import "myFramework/myFramework.h"` or `#import <myFramework/myFramework.h>`

Comment: Yep, that was it. "main.m" was hiding under "Supporting files".  I'm used to it being located in the same folder with all the other source. Maybe that changed at some point during Xcode's development or something, I dunno.  But either way -- all good, thanks!

Comment: I have moved my comment to an answer, so it is more easily found by others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect the issue with including C++ headers inside other headers is that an Objective-C source file gets to see the C++ header file, which upsets it.

If you have mixed C++/Objective-C++/Objective-C then you are probably better off only exposing a pure Objective-C interface to other modules in the project and include any C++ header files in the Objective-C++ source files only.

Alternatively make everything Objective-C++ and then you don't need to worry about it at all.

Hopefully this answers your second question as well.

Comment: All of the files in the App project are .mm (ObjC++) so not sure what ObjC file would be #including my framework header without my knowledge?  As for the Interface, I use C++11 strings for everything so really need the consumer of the framework to use them too.

Comment: You'd have to post the complete compiler error message in order to figure that out.

Comment: Yours plus Sergio's answer (see above) lead me to the culprit. Doing a /facepalm at the moment...

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure that you get the error while compiling the `myViewController.mm` file?

Check if `myViewController.h` is imported into some other, non ObjC++ file (and that that one is the file that fails to compile).

Comment: This doesn't seem to be very different from my answer.  What does it add?

Comment: I wrote that initially as a comment. Since the OP stated in their answer: "Yep, that was it. "main.m" was hiding under "Supporting files", I thought of having this as an answer.